# Different Data Lines on Kendo UI Graphs

Tags: user-interface, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a Kendo UI line chart.

This has x axis intervals of 28 days and data plotted against this every 28 days.

I want to know if its possible to add a second line but with data plotted daily rather than every 28 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! This type of series are called `scatterLines` and basically for each series you have to provide an array of pairs with the `x` and `y` values.

If for the first series you provide values 0, 28, 56... and for the second 0, 1, 2... You get what you want.

Example:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [
        { type: "scatterLine", data: [[0, 4], [28, 2], [56, 3]] },
        { type: "scatterLine", data: [[1, 2], [2, 3]] }
    ]
});
```

Check it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/U7SvD/

Comment: Great thanks, that looks good.  My x axis are dates though.  So starting at 01/01/2014 for example then incrementing by 28 days.  Can you do this with scatter lines?